# Tamper-proof configuration files in .NET?

Tags: .net, digital-signature

We ship a .NET application with an associated configuration file. Our consultants create the configuration file during installation. We'd like to make it hard for the client to tamper with the configuration file.

What avenues do we have?

At the moment, I'm thinking about signing the configuration file with our private key and verifying it against the public key when the application starts. I'd then hide the public key in the EXE somewhere.

How might I go about doing this? Are there better ways to do this?

*Note: I'm **aware** that this will **not prevent** a **determined** attacker. We're looking at closing off some of the easiest routes and moving the effort required into deliberate, rather than negligent, infringement.*

Comment: Your signature approach will work quite well, we use it all he time. Your client might patch your .exe or .dll to substitute another key, but I guess you don't give any warranties on binary-patched executables ;-)

Comment: @EugenRieck: are there good ways to "hide" the public key in the EXE, or should I just embed it as a resource?

Comment: We never "hide" it, just have it as a hardcoded byte[] - 2048 bit public keys are not that easy to factor.

Comment: For now, I'm just embedding the public key as a base64-encoded string. We might obfuscate that a little in future.

Comment: You really don't need to obfuscate it! Repeating the signing process will necessitate binary patching this way or another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense. You are shipping a configuration file. It's used for configuring the application. But you don't want it to be changed? So then it can't be used to configure the application. So, then why even bother with a configuration file? Why not just embed it as a resource in the application itself?

What am I missing?

Edit, to respond to your new information:

Use [XMLDSIG](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/). [Sign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx) the `app.config`. [Verify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229950.aspx) the signature.

Comment: +1 Embed in a resource file - that's a good suggestion.  Wish I had thought of that.

Comment: Our consultant configures it during installation. It's not a shrink-wrap application. Updated question.

Comment: Then use `XMLDSIG`. You can sign with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx. You can provide a tool to the consultant after he is done configuring the application. You can verify signatures with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229950.aspx. Note that, as usual, you have a key handling problem.

Comment: Fails with "Unrecognised configuration section Signature" :-(

Comment: You need to use `System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler` to force the configuration engine to ignore the `Signature` section. Sorry, I don't have time for a full-fledged example, but if you Google, it, I'm sure you can find an example of using this. The syntax would be something like `<configSections>
 <section name="Signature" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler" />
</configSections>`. Let me know if you need more detail. I might be able to come back later and fill in some things.

Comment: Found something: http://www.beefycode.com/post/Managing-AppConfig-Integrity-using-Xml-Digital-Signatures.aspx.

Comment: Done. I'll mark this as accepted; I don't know if you'll want to come back and tidy it up a bit for future generations...

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt sections of your configuration file with the [aspnet_regiis command line utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx).  It uses the DPAPI by default (I believe) but it can also support other encryption algorithms.  So you can use this to encrypt your connection string or app setting sections of your file (or any other sections).

Comment: OK. I don't want it encrypted. I want it signed. DPAPI uses machine-/user-keys, which means that we can't sign it here and ship it to the customer. How might I use it without this limitation?

Comment: I'm not sure how you install the application, but since aspnet_regiis is a command line utility, you can just script its execution during install.  The .NET Framework comes with two `ProtectectedConfigurationProviders` - one for RSA, one for DPAPI.  But you can implement your own, too, depending on your needs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.protectedconfigurationprovider.aspx   Not sure if that's what you're looking for or not.