# Verify XMLDSIG chain in .NET?

Tags: .net, x509, xml-dsig

I'm using XMLDSIG to [sign a configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989828/tamper-proof-configuration-files-in-net). I'd like my CA to be able to issue keys that can be used to sign XML. I'd then like to verify that the XML was signed with a key issued by my CA.

How do I get the signing certificate out of the `SignedXml` object? How do I follow the certificate chain back to a specific CA?

Note that the public key for my CA will be stored in my executable, rather than the certificate store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To attach arbitrary certificates to an XML-DSIG file, add an [`<X509Data>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-X509Data). To do this in .NET, use:

```
signedXml.KeyInfo.AddClause(
    new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate, X509IncludeOption.WholeChain));
```

To extract the certificates from the XML file, use:

```
var certificates = signedXml.KeyInfo.OfType<KeyInfoX509Data>().Single();
```

You can then verify the chain by using the following:

```
var chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.AddRange(
    certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().ToArray());
var chainIsOk = chain.Build(signingCertificate);
```

To figure out which certificate was actually used for signing (and hence the value of `signingCertificate`), you need to find the included certificate that [matches the key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9178479/8446) returned from `CheckSignatureReturningKey`.

Comment: Just saved me about a day of research.  :)

Comment: @Spence more like 3-4 days :)