# How can I compare public keys in .NET?

Tags: .net, x509, xml-dsig

I've got an [`X509Certificate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) containing a public key. I've got an [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) (which came from calling [`SignedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.checksignaturereturningkey.aspx)), also containing a public key.

I want to find out if one came from the other. How can I compare the two?

Comment: Could you just compare the PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData properties of each X509Certificate2 object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the [PublicKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.PublicKey);k(PublicKey);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property of signing certificates in the [SignedXml.KeyIfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.KeyInfo);k(KeyInfo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) with signing key output from [SignedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey);k(CheckSignatureReturningKey);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true). This C# extension method does the job for me:

```
public static bool CheckSignatureReturningCertificate(this SignedXml signedXml, out X509Certificate2 signingCertificate)
{
    signingCertificate = null;
    AsymmetricAlgorithm signingKey;
    bool isValid = signedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey(out signingKey);
    if (isValid)
    {
        IEnumerable<X509Certificate2> keyInfoCertificates =
            signedXml.KeyInfo.OfType<KeyInfoX509Data>()
                .SelectMany(x => x.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>());

        signingCertificate = keyInfoCertificates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PublicKey.Key == signingKey);
        if (signingCertificate == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Signing certificate not found in KeyInfo.");
        }
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
X509Certificate2 signingCertificate = null;
bool isValid = signedXml.CheckSignatureReturningCertificate(out signingCertificate);
if(isValid)
{
    // signingCertificate now contains the certificate used to sign
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. How can `FirstOrDefault(x => x.PublicKey.Key == signingKey);` compare if the keys are the same, or compares the references of the two objects. I have the same scenario, and this line of code always returns `null` for `signingCertificate`

Answer (score 2):

The public key parameters for the RSA algorithm are `{e, n}`, the exponent and the modulus. In .NET, these are available from the [`RSAParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters.aspx) struct. The other fields represent the private key.

So, to compare an `X509Certificate2` and an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` for public key equality, you can just grab these parameters:

```
AsymmetricAlgorithm signingKey;
bool signatureIsVerified = signedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey(out signingKey);

var certificateParameters =
    ((RSA)certificate.PublicKey.Key).ExportParameters(
        includePrivateParameters: false);
var signingParameters = signingKey.ExportParameters(
        includePrivateParameters: false);
bool areEqual =
    ByteArrayEquals(certificateParameters.Exponent,
                    signingParameters.Exponent)
    && ByteArrayEquals(certificateParameters.Modulus,
                    signingParameters.Modulus);
```

You'll have to implement `ByteArrayEquals`, because there's [no good way to do it in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43289/8446).

If you're using DSA rather than RSA, the public key is made up of `{p, q, g, y}`.