# C# Signing XML document with X509Chain

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, x509certificate2, signedxml

I have one question regarding signing `XmlDocument`with a chain of certificates.My current try is to load the root, intermediate and the signing certificates separately, and add them to the `KeyInfoX509Data` of the `KeyInfo` class.

```
var keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
var keyInfoData = new KeyInfoX509Data(_certificateManager.Certificate);
keyInfoData.AddCertificate(_certificateManager.Intermediate);
keyInfoData.AddCertificate(_certificateManager.Root);
keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);
```

Something like this.
Then I assign the `SignedXml` `KeyInfo` property with the `keyInfo` variable. Then i call the `.ComputeSignature()` method.
My question is - is this the right way to sign the xml message, or recently I found out the class `X509Chain`, and I have to use in in some way, because I want to sign the xml with the whole chain.

Thanks in advance,

Julian

Comment: See if my solution at following posting helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722997/saml-assertion-in-a-xml-using-c-sharp/46724392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161835/verify-xmldsig-chain-in-net) is what helped me!

```
signedXml.KeyInfo.AddClause(
new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate, X509IncludeOption.WholeChain));
```

Hope that helps other with the same problem!